# CSS: count elements and add divider after x amount of elements automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive layout using CSS.

Basically, I need to know if it is possible to count elements and when it reaches x amount, then add a divider after the elements.

To explain this better, I've created this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/onjL7kn4/)

as you can see, I have an element with a class name `.divider` which comes after the 5th `.beers` elements.

How can I show the `.divider` element after each 5th `.beers` ?

I hope this makes sense and someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

My CSS:

```
.wrapper{
width:100%;
}

.content{
width:960px;
height:500px;

}

.beers{
position: relative;
width: 166px;
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 5px;
height: 107px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px dotted #e46a10;
}

.divider{

  display: block;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Add a divider how? Not a div I'm assuming. You'd need JS for that. CSS can't ADD actual elements to the DOM

Comment: @Paulie_D, the divider that's shown in my fiddle... so basically, count the .beers and when it reaches 5, add a divider and then count the next 5 and add the divider and so on and so forth.

Comment: No...CSS can't do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D, would jquery be able to do that?

Answer (score 5):

There's a trick way to do this, and requires clever use of pseudo elements. You can move your divider styles into the `.beers::after` pseudo element, and target every `:nth-child(5n)` class. It would look something like this:

```
.beers {
  position: relative;
  width: 166px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 107px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px dotted #e46a10;
}

.beers:nth-child(5n)::after {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  content: "";
}
```

Edit: Upon close inspection of your code, it seems your beers are inline block elements, and you want the separation to break them every 5. So while this is a clever trick, it may not give you the desired effect.

Comment: @ajm: You would need `nth-of-type(5n)` at least to match every 5th instead of the 5th element, though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, but faster x) Well done sir. Also can you clarify what's the difference between `nth:child()` and `nth-of-type()` because i never really understood.

Comment: This is not the solution

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way, as the 6th block will clear the 5th and the dotted line will stretch the content divs width. Also we're adding the dotted line to the top of the 6th element, removing the line from the bottom of the stack if it ends on the last 5th element.

Link to your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/onjL7kn4/4/

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
}

.beers {
  position: relative;
  width: 166px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 107px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px dotted #e46a10;
}


.content > div:nth-of-type(5n+6) {
  clear: left;
}

.content > div:nth-of-type(5n+6):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 960px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  transform: translateY(-12px);
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="wrapper">

  <div align="center" class="content">

    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>
    <div class="beers"></div>

  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: @Mi-Creativity no harm adding a link to the fiddle and including the code? Not sure what your point is.

Comment: I meant, in the CSS code in your fiddle you have `.content > div:nth-of-type(5n+6):after `, while here in the above code you have `.content > div:nth-of-type(5n+6):before`

Comment: oh i see @Mi-Creativity, thanks. Ill update the fiddle. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the styles you have in your `divider` class are the only effects you want the divider for, you can work with `nth-child` and don't have to use pseudo-elements whatsoever:

```css
.beers:nth-child(5n) {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
</ul>
```

---

**EDIT** And a version to be compatible with `inline-block` elements (which assumes that only five elements fit per row, which you likely have anyway if you need this - if I'm wrong, floats are the way to go):

```css
.beers {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
  <li class="beers">Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it wouldn't work if the `li` has `display:inline-block` as @NickSalloum stated in his answer already https://jsfiddle.net/qpr6150v/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: True - I added another answer that works with inline-block elements. I suppose this is the answer dedicated to solving things without floats, pseudo-elements or javascript ;) (but I usually prefer simple solutions over complex ones)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you couldn't find any perfect CSS solution, here's javascript code -both pure javascript and jQuery- pick what suits you:

**Pure javascript: [jsFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/brebd4a7/4/)**

```js
var brs = document.querySelectorAll('.beers');

for (var i = 0; i < brs.length; ++i) {

  if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
    // create the new divider div and add the relative class to it
    var divider = document.createElement('div');
    divider.classList.add('divider');

    //insert the newly created div.divider
    brs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divider, brs[i].nextSibling);
  }
}
```

---

**jQuery: [jsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/mb1bav1j/2/)**

```js
var brs = $('.beers');

brs.each(function(i) {
  if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
    $('<div class="divider"></div>').insertAfter(brs[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Umm, what is the downvote for? if it's because this is a javascript solution, the OP already has `javascript` and `jquery` tags, and in a comment the OP asked "*would jquery be able to do that*?", also in my answer "*Just in case you couldn't find any perfect CSS solution*. Anyways, thanks downvoter.

Comment: nice solution, I'm not sure why this was downvoted as it is answering the OP's question, infact +2 for adding both vanilla and jquery imo.